# How to create SHA1 digest in jOOQ postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, hash, jooq, sha1

I need to implement the following part of the query in jOOQ `digest(callables.fasten_uri, 'sha1'::text)` from postgres, however, I could not find anywhere such functionality. Could someone point me to it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL has hundreds of built-in functions. It wouldn't make sense to support them all in the jOOQ API. But you can work around this limitation easily in two ways:

- Use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)
- Use [code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/) of the `pg_catalog` schema, where all these functions are stored